# Hadoop : DataNode change directory not taking effect

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-yarn, hadoop2

We are using hadoop 2.7.3 changed the hdfs-site.xml to point to new directory provided permissions on new directory too ...and ran start-dfs.sh and stop-dfs.sh ..on name node ...but changes are not taking effect it still points to the old directory ...

Am I missing anything while doing the configuration changes? And how can we make sure to use the new directory?

it's a multi node cluster

this is the hdfs-site.xml on name node

```
<configuration>

    <property>
        <name>dfs.replication</name>
        <value>2</value>
    </property>

    <property>
        <name>dfs.name.dir</name>
        <value>file:///test/hadoop/hadoopinfra/hdfs/namenode</value>
    </property>

    <property>
        <name>hadoop.tmp.dir</name>
        <value>file:///tmp/hadoop/data</value>
    </property>

    <property>
        <name>dfs.datanode.du.reserved</name>
        <value>2368709120</value>
    </property>

    <property>
        <name>dfs.datanode.fsdataset.volume.choosing.policy</name>
        <value>org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.fsdataset.AvailableSpaceVolumeChoosingPolicy</value>
    </property>

    <property>
        <name>dfs.datanode.available-space-volume-choosing-policy.balanced-space-preference-fraction</name>
        <value>1.0</value>
    </property>

</configuration>
```

this is the hdfs-site.xml under data node

```
<configuration>

    <property>
        <name>dfs.replication</name>
        <value>2</value>
    </property>

    <property>
        <name>dfs.data.dir</name>
        <value>file:///test/hadoop/hadoopinfra/hdfs/datanode</value>
    </property>

    <property>
        <name>hadoop.tmp.dir</name>
        <value>file:///tmp/hadoop/data</value>
    </property>

    <property>
        <name>dfs.datanode.du.reserved</name>
        <value>2368709120</value>
    </property>

    <property>
        <name>dfs.datanode.fsdataset.volume.choosing.policy</name>
        <value>org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.fsdataset.AvailableSpaceVolumeChoosingPolicy</value>
    </property>

    <property>
        <name>dfs.datanode.available-space-volume-choosing-policy.balanced-space-preference-fraction</name>
        <value>1.0</value>
    </property>

</configuration>
```

Comment: Pseudo Distributed Cluster or Multinode Cluster? Also please update the post with the configuration file.

Comment: updated the question with info